# Im integrating with my auctions website but the api dint working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios, cloudinary

im building a auctions website in MERN Stack and tried using CLOUDINARY for storage, but my upload api for cloudinary is not working and it giving me a bad request error so im sharing the code, every help will be appreciated

this is the upload Controller of the website in nodejs here im uploading image and retriving the public id of cloudinary

```js
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require("dotenv").config();

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.SECRET,
});

exports.uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
    }

    const uploadOptions = { resource_type: "auto" };

    cloudinary.uploader
      .upload_stream(uploadOptions, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Error uploading image to Cloudinary:", error);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error uploading image" });
        }

        if (!result || !result.secure_url) {
          console.error("Invalid response from Cloudinary:", result);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: "Invalid response from Cloudinary" });
        }

        const uploadedImage = {
          public_id: result.public_id,
          secure_url: result.secure_url,
          format: result.format,
          width: result.width,
          height: result.height,
        };

        // Check if the format is supported (e.g., you can add more supported formats as needed)
        const supportedFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"];
        if (!supportedFormats.includes(result.format.toLowerCase())) {
          console.error("Unsupported image format:", result.format);
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "Unsupported image format" });
        }

        res.json({ message: "Image uploaded to Cloudinary", uploadedImage });
      })
      .end(req.file.buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during image upload:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

// exports.upload = upload.single("image");

exports.getDownloadURLFromCloud = async (req, res) => {
  const imageId = req.params.public_id;

  try {
    const result = await cloudinary.api.resource(imageId);

    if (!result.secure_url) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Image not found" });
    }

    const downloadURL = result.secure_url;
    res.json({ downloadURL });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching image from Cloudinary:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error fetching image from Cloudinary" });
  }
};
```

this is the route of upload

```js
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const unlinkFile = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const isAuth = require("../middlewares/isAuth");
const {
  uploadImage,
  getDownloadURLFromCloud,
} = require("../controllers/upload");

const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads" });

// @route   GET /upload/image/:key
// @desc    Get image with key
// @access  protected
router.get("/image/:imageId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fileBuffer = await getDownloadURLFromCloud(req.params.key);

    res.status(200).send(fileBuffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: { msg: "Server Error" } });
  }
});

router.post("/image", isAuth, upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;

  try {
    const result = await uploadImage(file);
    await unlinkFile(file.path);
    res.status(200).json({ imagePath: `/upload/image/${result.public_id}` });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: { msg: "Server Error" } });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
``
```

Comment: _"... giving me a bad request error"_    What is the full error message?

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the following line:
console.error("Error uploading image to Cloudinary:", error);
If Cloudinary returns an error, you'll see more details there.

Another thing worth checking is if the 500 may actually be returned by your server - do you see the 500 in your server logs?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
    at MediaCard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2832:25)